# Replace all instances of numbers in a dataframe with strings R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I am looking at replacing all numbers in a dataframe with words/strings.   Each number will be replaced with the exact same word.  e.g. all instances of the number 5 should be replaced with 'banana', all instances of the number 10 with 'kiwi', and so on.

Here is a sample dataframe. Rownames and colnames are numbers too:

```
#    1  2  3  4  5  6
#1   7  7  7  7  7  7
#2   5  5  5  5  5  5
#3   4  4  4  4  4  4
#4   8  8  8  8  8  8
#5   1  1  1  1  1  1
#6   2  2  2  2  2  2
#7   6  6  6  6  3  3
#8   3  3  3  3  6  6
#9  10 10 10 10 10 10
#10 11 11 11 11 11 11
#11 12 12 12 12 12 12
#12  9  9  9  9  9  9
```

Here is the sample data (mydf) for reproducing this:

```
mydf<-structure(c(7, 5, 4, 8, 1, 2, 6, 3, 10, 11, 12, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 
1, 2, 6, 3, 10, 11, 12, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 1, 2, 6, 3, 10, 11, 12, 
9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 1, 2, 6, 3, 10, 11, 12, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 1, 2, 3, 
6, 10, 11, 12, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 11, 12, 9), .Dim = c(12L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")))
```

Here is a dataframe (mydata) I constructed showing  which number should be replaced with which word/fruit:

```
mydata <- data.frame(nums = c(1:12))                     
mydata$fruits<-c("apple", "pear", "orange", "melon", "banana", "grape", "pineapple",      "mango", "lemon", "kiwi", "guava", "peach")
```

I have tried looking through similarly named threads, but they mainly discuss changing certain parts of dataframes (e.g. specific variables or specific observations), not the contents of the whole dataframe.

I tried using multiple gsub commands, but this doesn't work for multiple reasons. I guess I need to use a function to apply across all variables in the df, but not sure what.

The final result should look something like this:

```
      1           2           3           4           5           6          
1  "pineapple" "pineapple" "pineapple" "pineapple" "pineapple" "pineapple"
2  "banana"    "banana"    "banana"    "banana"    "banana"    "banana"   
3  "melon"     "melon"     "melon"     "melon"     "melon"     "melon"    
4  "mango"     "mango"     "mango"     "mango"     "mango"     "mango"    
5  "apple"     "apple"     "apple"     "apple"     "apple"     "apple"    
6  "pear"      "pear"      "pear"      "pear"      "pear"      "pear"     
7  "grape"     "grape"     "grape"     "grape"     "orange"    "orange"   
8  "orange"    "orange"    "orange"    "orange"    "grape"     "grape"    
9  "kiwi"      "kiwi"      "kiwi"      "kiwi"      "kiwi"      "kiwi"     
10 "guava"     "guava"     "guava"     "guava"     "guava"     "guava"    
11 "peach"     "peach"     "peach"     "peach"     "peach"     "peach"    
12 "lemon"     "lemon"     "lemon"     "lemon"     "lemon"     "lemon"
```

Though ideally, the quote marks would not be visible (I'm not sure if this is possible though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `match`, which refers to a lookup vector (your `mydata`), returning the position in that vector of each element of another vector.

```
mydf[] <- mydata$fruits[match(mydf, mydata$nums)]
```

If you coerce to a `data.frame`, quotes aren't visible when you print the object to screen:

```
as.data.frame(mydf)

#            1         2         3         4         5         6
# 1  pineapple pineapple pineapple pineapple pineapple pineapple
# 2     banana    banana    banana    banana    banana    banana
# 3      melon     melon     melon     melon     melon     melon
# 4      mango     mango     mango     mango     mango     mango
# 5      apple     apple     apple     apple     apple     apple
# 6       pear      pear      pear      pear      pear      pear
# 7      grape     grape     grape     grape    orange    orange
# 8     orange    orange    orange    orange     grape     grape
# 9       kiwi      kiwi      kiwi      kiwi      kiwi      kiwi
# 10     guava     guava     guava     guava     guava     guava
# 11     peach     peach     peach     peach     peach     peach
# 12     lemon     lemon     lemon     lemon     lemon     lemon
```

Whether or not you coerce to `data.frame`, you can supply `quote=FALSE` to `write.table` or `write.csv` to prevent quotes appearing around character strings in the exported file.

Comment: Since the lookup data is already sorted, just `mydf[] <- mydata$fruits[mydf]` will work.

Comment: @thelatemail: Yep, baptiste mentioned the same. I gave a generally-applicable solution since I didn't want to assume the OP's real-life problem was as simple as the example.

Comment: Thanks.  This works great - as actually do all the suggestions.  It's great how such a problem can be solved in multiple ways.  Thanks too for the general solution.  Obviously, my real data issue is much more complex than the simple example ... and has nothing to do with fruit either!

Answer (score 0):

`replace` might work for you here.

```
> replace(mydf, seq_along(mydf), mydata[[2]][mydf])
#    1           2           3           4           5           6          
# 1  "pineapple" "pineapple" "pineapple" "pineapple" "pineapple" "pineapple"
# 2  "banana"    "banana"    "banana"    "banana"    "banana"    "banana"   
# 3  "melon"     "melon"     "melon"     "melon"     "melon"     "melon"    
# 4  "mango"     "mango"     "mango"     "mango"     "mango"     "mango"    
# 5  "apple"     "apple"     "apple"     "apple"     "apple"     "apple"    
# 6  "pear"      "pear"      "pear"      "pear"      "pear"      "pear"     
# 7  "grape"     "grape"     "grape"     "grape"     "orange"    "orange"   
# 8  "orange"    "orange"    "orange"    "orange"    "grape"     "grape"    
# 9  "kiwi"      "kiwi"      "kiwi"      "kiwi"      "kiwi"      "kiwi"     
# 10 "guava"     "guava"     "guava"     "guava"     "guava"     "guava"    
# 11 "peach"     "peach"     "peach"     "peach"     "peach"     "peach"    
# 12 "lemon"     "lemon"     "lemon"     "lemon"     "lemon"     "lemon"
```

And it can be wrapped with `as.data.frame` to remove quotes if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As the fruits are in the correct order and are indexed by `1:12`, you can use the entries of `mydf` to index into `mydata$fruits`:

```
apply(mydf, 2, function(x) mydata$fruits[x])
```

If the values are not in the correct order, or do not cover all possible values (have "holes"), you can use a factor to translate:

```
apply(mydf, 2, function(x) factor(x, levels=mydata$nums, labels=mydata$fruits))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach:

```
library(qdapTools)
as.data.frame(apply(mydf, 2, lookup, mydata))

##            1         2         3         4         5         6
## 1  pineapple pineapple pineapple pineapple pineapple pineapple
## 2     banana    banana    banana    banana    banana    banana
## 3      melon     melon     melon     melon     melon     melon
## 4      mango     mango     mango     mango     mango     mango
## 5      apple     apple     apple     apple     apple     apple
## 6       pear      pear      pear      pear      pear      pear
## 7      grape     grape     grape     grape    orange    orange
## 8     orange    orange    orange    orange     grape     grape
## 9       kiwi      kiwi      kiwi      kiwi      kiwi      kiwi
## 10     guava     guava     guava     guava     guava     guava
## 11     peach     peach     peach     peach     peach     peach
## 12     lemon     lemon     lemon     lemon     lemon     lemon
```